# Java-Selenium Allow Popup Window

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I got a problem when I create my automation project. Firefox is blocking our web app's popup window. I try to enable it from about:preferences#content. But when I run the test firefox still blocking it. I also tried to use setPreference(), but no luck as well. I can't use firefox user profile because eventually, this program will give to all the QA member. Here is the setPreference() code that I tried.

```
public void LoginCad(){

    //System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");

    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

    profile.setPreference("dom.disable_open_during_load", false);
    profile.setPreference("privacy.popups.disable_from_plugins", 0);
    profile.setPreference("privacy.popups.policy", 1);
    profile.setPreference("dom.max_script_run_time", "999");

    driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

    driver.get("http://172.16.1.133:8090/CADENCIE/servlet/app");
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I will recommand you to reset all firefox settings to default

Comment: Thank you for replying me. But why I should reset the settings. It will still block the popup window, right?

Comment: by default firefox will allow all the popup that appear, if not than it will show a dialog for your confirmation to allow an web app popup

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

1. Click on the permission symbol appears in the search bar in firfox browser.
   [image]
2. Click on right arrow displayed in first row then select **More Information**
3. Page Info dialog will open. Navigate to Permissions tab.
4. Scroll down to see Open pop-up windows. Change settings to **Allow**
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sandeep, But this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
profile.setPreference("browser.popups.showPopupBlocker", false);
```

Comment: I think Shi Tim has already mentioned that he has tried "setPreference"

Comment: Thanks for replying me. But I tried this at first time. With no luck. Thanks anyway.